# Splitting an Image into Parts Using writeableBitmap cropping in wp7

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, split

I am unable to take the image other that the default images available during the creation of the application. My code is

WriteableBitmap sourceBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
            sourceBitmap = sourceBitmap.FromContent(@"Images/viewback_collection.png");

I am getting error as Nullreference exception.

Answer (score 0):

set the build action of "viewback_collection.png" to content type by right clicking on the image > properties > Build action = Content